# How to prevent duplicate card widget on same product if i click more than one time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I use `provider` library state management for doing add to cart and basically i am a bit beginner in `provider`. So the issue i am facing is for example there are three products `laptop` , `iphone x` & `keyboard`. Now if i put `laptop` two times in the cart then in `cart page` it displays two laptop `card` widgets, instead i want to display only one `card` widget in that `laptop qty: 2`. And second issue is that i have implemented `+` and `-` button in each `card` widget in `cart page` and if i click on `+` or `-` button then it should reflect on `qty` and also on `total price`. Really appreciate if you help me in this problem.

> main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => Cart(),
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final List<Item> items = [
    Item(title: 'laptop ', price: 500.0),
    Item(title: 'iphone x ', price: 400.0),
    Item(title: 'keyboard ', price: 40.0),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Cart>(builder: (context, cart, child) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Shopping cart'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.shopping_cart,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CheckoutPage()));
                    },
                  ),
                  Text(cart.count.toString())
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index].title),
              subtitle: Text(items[index].price.toString()),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.add),
              onTap: () {
                cart.add(items[index]);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

> CheckoutPage.dart

```
class CheckoutPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckoutPageState createState() => _CheckoutPageState();
}

class _CheckoutPageState extends State<CheckoutPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Cart>(
      builder: (context, cart, child) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Checkout Page [\$ ${cart.totalPrice}]'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(cart.totalPrice);
                    },
                    child: Text('Check'))
              ],
            ),
            body: cart.basketItems.length == 0
                ? Text('no items in your cart')
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: cart.basketItems.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(cart.basketItems[index].title),
                          subtitle: Row(
                            children: [
                              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('+')),
                              Text(cart.basketItems[index].qty.toString()),
                              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('-')),
                            ],
                          ),
                          trailing: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () {
                              cart.remove(cart.basketItems[index]);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> Item.dart

```
class Item {
  String title;
  double price;
  Item({this.title, this.price});
}
```

> Cart.dart

```
class Cart extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> _items = [];
  double _totalPrice = 0.0;

  void add(Item item) {
    _items.add(item);
    _totalPrice += item.price;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void remove(Item item) {
    _totalPrice -= item.price;
    _items.remove(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get count {
    return _items.length;
  }

  double get totalPrice {
    return _totalPrice;
  }

  List<Item> get basketItems {
    return _items;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try before adding item add a certain function that will look up for the duplicate item like this

e.g. inside on add

Add qty on you class on item.dart so that in every add item you should have default qty to one then goes this below.

```
class Item {
  String title;
  double price;
  int qty;
  Item({this.title, this.price,this.qty});
}

void add(Item item) {
  final itemIsExist  = _items.where((e)=> e.title == item.title);
    if(itemIsExist.isNotEmpty){
   // if item exist and you want to add +1 on qty
   final addQty = _items.firstWhere((e)=> e.title == item.title);
   addQty.qty= addQty.qty+1;
   // do your thing here to calculate again the total
}else{
 _items.add(item);
    _totalPrice += item.price;
    notifyListeners();
}
  }
```

Comment: Is it `final itemIsExist  = items.where((e)=> e.title == item.title);`  or 
`final itemIsExist  = _items.where((e)=> e.title == item.title);` because i am getting an error on `items`.

Comment: I want to check if exists then make qty 2. How to do that ?

Comment: @MohammedNabil try above i edited some

Comment: I am getting an error `The method '+' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: +(1)`
If i click two times on single product.

Comment: Hmm try to change the +1 to ++ so it will be addQty.qty++

Comment: Ok, now error is not coming but in `checkout_page.dart` , on this line of code `Text(cart.basketItems[index].qty.toString()),` is showing `null`.

Comment: Also on adding item you should fill the qty just 1 on the value.Hmmm try to rebuild the list also.Can you update the code above in check_page.dart.

Comment: Updated the `checkout_page.dart`.

Comment: By the way after i restart again the error is coming `The method '+' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: +(1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240142/discussion-between-arbiter-chil-and-mohammed-nabil).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating another variable on base class and extend it for model, But now let's follow your way.

We can create a [`map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map-class.html) to iterate items on `_CheckoutPageState` and create a `Set`, but we need to count the item quantity,

We can take the help of map in this case and place it just under `Consumer builder` before returning `Scaffold`

```dart
Map<String, int> itemsMap = {};

for (final item in cart._items) {
  if (!itemsMap.containsKey(item.title)) {
    itemsMap.putIfAbsent(item.title, () => 1);
  } else {
    itemsMap.update(item.title, (value) => itemsMap[item.title]! + 1);
  }
}
```

And uses will be like

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  final keys = itemsMap.keys.toList();
  final count = itemsMap.values.toList();
  return Card(
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(keys[index].toString()),
      subtitle: Row(
        children: [
          TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('+')),
          Text(count[index].toString()),
          TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('-')),
        ],
      ),
```

**State class**

```dart
class _CheckoutPageState extends State<CheckoutPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Cart>(
      builder: (context, cart, child) {
        Map<String, int> itemsMap = {};

        for (final item in cart.basketItems) {
          if (!itemsMap.containsKey(item.title)) {
            itemsMap.putIfAbsent(item.title, () => 1);
          } else {
            itemsMap.update(item.title, (value) => itemsMap[item.title]! + 1);
          }
        }
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Checkout Page [\$ ${cart.totalPrice}]'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(cart.totalPrice);
                    },
                    child: Text('Check'))
              ],
            ),
            body: cart.basketItems.length == 0
                ? Text('no items in your cart')
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: itemsMap.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final keys = itemsMap.keys.toList();
                      final count = itemsMap.values.toList();
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(keys[index].toString()),
                          subtitle: Row(
                            children: [
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    cart.add(
                                      Item(
                                        title: keys[index].toString(),
                                        price: keys[index].trim() == "laptop"
                                            ? 500
                                            : keys[index].trim() == "iphone x"
                                                ? 400
                                                : 40,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: Text('+')),
                              Text(count[index].toString()),
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    cart.remove(Item(
                                      title: keys[index].toString(),
                                      price: keys[index].trim() == "laptop"
                                          ? 500
                                          : keys[index].trim() == "iphone x"
                                              ? 400
                                              : 40,
                                    ));
                                  },
                                  child: Text('-')),
                            ],
                          ),
                          trailing: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () {
                              cart.remove(cart.basketItems[
                                  index]); // remove match all on remove method
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where i put this line of code in `_CheckoutPageState` ?
`Map<String, int> itemsMap = {};

for (final item in cart._items) {
  if (!itemsMap.containsKey(item.title)) {
    itemsMap.putIfAbsent(item.title, () => 1);
  } else {
    itemsMap.update(item.title, (value) => itemsMap[item.title]! + 1);
  }
}`

Comment: Inside consumer builder

Comment: on for loop `for (final item in cart._items)` getting an error on "_items" that is `The getter '_items' isn't defined for the type 'Cart'`.

Comment: Ok you are using separate file for class, in this case use `basketItems` instead of `_items`

Comment: What about `+` and `-` button ?

Comment: updated, I think better will be using base class and increment quantity

Comment: But this is hardcoded not dynamic